# An error occurs when you run the log4j2 jar

Tags: intellij-idea, jar, log4j2

When you run the project in intellij idea error occurs. As soon as I collect the project into a jar file and run it, it errors.

What could be the problem, if the configuration file is correct?

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
    %d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n
```

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="ERROR">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %p: %msg -- %l %n"/>
        </Console>
        <!-- Файловый аппендер -->
        <File name="file" fileName="d:\backup.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%-5p][%-20c{1}] [%-20M:%L] - %msg%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: *What could be the problem, if the configuration file is correct?* The configuration file isn't correct. That's what your error messages are saying.

Comment: and what is right?

Answer (score 0):

the error corrected version of apache-log4j-2.3
apparently in the version apache-log4j-2.6.2 bug.

Comment: what does this mean?